# MNA matrix of a vacuum tube

Tags: modeling, vacuum-tube, nodal-analysis

I've been working on a project involving a digital model of a vacuum tube. We're currently experimenting with a Wave Digital Filter approach.

Now I've been reading Kurt Wegner's fascinating work and I understand that I must derive an MNA matrix of a tube, but I'm struggling to understand exactly how would I do that, what model of a tube I should use, etc.

In *[THE FENDER BASSMAN 5F6-A FAMILY OF PREAMPLIFIER CIRCUITS—A WAVE DIGITAL FILTER CASE STUDY](http://dafx16.vutbr.cz/)* paper it's mentioned in section 3.2 that the derivation of the matrix is available on a link pasted in the references section, but it has been taken down, unfortunately.

I would be extremely grateful if any of you guys could help me with this, or help me find that link that's missing from that paper.

Comment: It's been a LONG TIME since I read [this paper on WDF](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jingjiez/portfolio/gtr-amp-sim/pdfs/Wave%20Digital%20Filters%20Theory%20and%20Practice.pdf). And I only spent a little of my time playing with it. Are you able to use these techniques to model a simple LC filter? If not, then you may need to get up to speed before writing anything yourself. As far as the link, use the internet wayback machine to see if it captured it for you.

Comment: I tried the Wayback Machine but there's nothing there regarding this link. Well I'm comfortable with modelling simple circuits and components with WDF. The thing is regarding R-type adaptors that model highly nonlinear components such as vacuum tubes. It's been hard to find sources that explain this part with enough detail, so I welcome any help regarding it

Comment: There were 4 papers presented on WDF at the 19th symposium. One you've mentioned is [The Fender Bassman 5F6 - A Family of Preamplifier Circuits — A Wave
Digital Filter Case Study](http://dafx16.vutbr.cz/dafxpapers/37-DAFx-16_paper_53-PN.pdf).

Comment: The others were [A Computational Model of the Hammond Organ Vibrato/Chorus Using Wave Digital Filters](http://dafx16.vutbr.cz/dafxpapers/38-DAFx-16_paper_54-PN.pdf), [RT-WDF - A Modular Wave Digital Filter Library with Support for Arbitrary Topologies and Multiple Nonlinearities](http://dafx16.vutbr.cz/dafxpapers/40-DAFx-16_paper_35-PN.pdf), and [Resolving Grouped Nonlinearities in Wave Digital Filters Using Iterative Techniques](http://dafx16.vutbr.cz/dafxpapers/39-DAFx-16_paper_14-PN_updated.pdf). Have you gone through all these? At least two of them focus on dealing with nonlinearities.

Comment: I'm no expert on this stuff. In fact, when I was reading through that 1985/1986 paper so many years back, I didn't have any of the mathematical basis to make more than the simpler uses of it. And I dropped investing time in it as I didn't have anyone wanting to pay for my further education there. ;) One thing I did take away from that reading is that one really needs to have a solid background just to be able to select from among the many different ways a single modeling can be achieved using these methods. There's a lot of art to it, my sense, drawn from a substantial background in filters.

Comment: Would a SPICE model suffice?  Some are available for the most common tube types.  I don't know offhand how accurate or reliable they are.